# Pentaho Spoon: JavaScript split is only putting one element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, pentaho

I have strings in the following format in Pentaho Spoon:

"0.31;0.45"

Now I want these to split in Javascript

```
var str = "0.31;0.45"
var res1 = str.split(";");
```

However, this returns an array where only the first element is filled as

```
res1[0] = "0.310.45"
```

While I'm expecting this:

```
res1[0] = "0.31"
res1[1] = "0.45"
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been looking for quite some time now but didn't discover any solution.

The string has been sanitized before, because it was imported from an excel sheet where enters were added between the different values:

```
str = strold.replace(new RegExp("\n", "gi"), ";");
```

Snippet of the excel sheet data can be found here (can't disclose complete records due to the sensitive nature of the data):

[Exceldata](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iowuyrou6o0hb0d/exampledata.xls?dl=0)

Any pointers on the right track will be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: No it doesn't, it returns an array with both values in it, anything else would be impossible.

Comment: The code you've provided does not replicate this issue. Are you 100% sure your `str` variable is equal to `"0.31;0.45"`?

Comment: works just fine... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/an284avm/1/

Comment: It looks like the problem is elsewhere. You need to post more of the code, preferably as a snippet which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Looks like your `str` is filtered or sanitized somewhere before.

Comment: That is correct, I'm using Pentaho Spoon to do a transformation from an excel sheet to a certain output I need for our database. Before this I removed all enters in the excel cells using:

str = strold.replace(new RegExp("\n", "gi"), ";");

Comment: Obviously the problem is in the input string. Dump it to the browser console just before splitting.

Comment: This works for me in Pentaho Kettle after Excel-Input of the string test1=0.31;0.45
var str = test1;
var split = str.split(";");
var res1 = split[0];
var res2 = split[1];

I think you just need a variable like "split" in my example to get it right

Comment: I posted above with an additional possibility as an answer, hope it works!

Comment: Seb, I just commented to provide  you with some example data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in a Modified JavaScript step, this should word fine:

After Excel-Input of the field `test1` with value "0.31;0.45" (as string) your JS-Code should look like this:

```
var str = test1;
var split = str.split(";");
var res1 = split[0];
var res2 = split[1];
```

The new fields `res1` and `res2` now show the splitted values. I think your problem was a missing second variable here like `split` in my code above, maybe a kettle-specific thing...

As a second possible way to solve this without a JavaScript-Step use the `Split-Fields`-step:
After Excel input set the step `Split-Fields`. Here set the field to split (in my testscenario `test1`), set the delimiter (`;`) and define the two new fields.

Hope it works!

Comment: Splitting fields is not an option as I have this in multiple fields and in the end I want to have a field that  contains the sum for all those values for each record. Splitting would create a lot of duplicate records.
I did exactly like you showed, however, I still have the same WRONG result. I've uploaded a snippet of the excel sheet (I can't  disclose complete records due to the sensitive nature of the data):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iowuyrou6o0hb0d/exampledata.xls?dl=0

Comment: ok, if your code after input looks like this (please c&p in JS-Step with your example-sheet as input):

var split1 = Str1.replace(new RegExp("\n", "gi"), ";");
split1 = split1.split(";");
var res1 = split1[0];
var res2 = split1[1];

 you still get a wrong result for res1?

Comment: Haha now at least I know I'm not the only one with the problem. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Hi Seb,
Were you able to find something out yet?? :)

Comment: No sorry. It's at least interesting ;) If it's possible, I would try to work with common CSV-format. Maybe a shell-script can help deleting the \n's while nothing else is damaged. If I get ideas with more value, I'll let you know.

Comment: Just one idea: Maybe you can use the split fields step. Then you have the values in a row and can sum them up back to str1 (you mentioned sum up so maybe you don't need the values, but the result)